# Kolmogorov-Smirnov vs simple area difference estimation to compare two statistical models

Tags: goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, cumulative-distribution-function

Could anyone explain, or point some references that I can locate this, **how KS compares to the relative area estimation method**?

It is known that Kolmogorov-Smirnov, among other famous similar approaches, can be used to assess how close two cumulative distribution functions are and it is usually referred as two sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. Basically it returns the maximum difference between the two CDFs.

After quite a few searches I still don't know what are the actual benefits of using such approach though. For me, the simple math: area of the absolute difference of the two CDF divided by the area of the ideal CDF (i.e.: **area(abs(F1-F2))/area(F1)**  ) would give a percentile number which has a more meaningful and intuitive interpretation.

Comment: I think what you refer to is a Berk-Jones test.
Berk, Robert H., and Douglas H. Jones. “Goodness-of-Fit Test Statistics That Dominate the Kolmogorov Statistics.” Zeitschrift Für Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie Und Verwandte Gebiete 47, no. 1 (January 1979): 47–59. doi:10.1007/BF00533250.